# Comparing two books on 'Homological Algebra' by Charles Weibel and Cartan & Eilenberg

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, homological-algebra

I'm interested in keep learning deep theories of homological algebra.

(For example, I want to keep getting familiar with the theory of etale cohomology or algebraic K-theory and so on)

And it seems that one of the most modern textbook on the homological algebra is the book written by Weibel.

However, I find it hard to read as it leaves many details as exercises.

Therefore, I've been reading the book of Cartan and Eilenberg.

At least for me, the good thing about the book of Cartan and Eilenberg is that it contains all the details. But since the book is a classic, I think that Weibel's book must have some advantages.

So my question is do both books cover the same materials with difference only in the style of exposition? (Cartan & Eilenberg's book old fashioned while Weibel's book new style?)

Or is there some difference in the materials (or the point of view of some of the materials) covered?

; Is there some chapter of Weibel's book that can be a complement to the book of Cartan & Eilenberg?

By the way, if you think there are some other advantages of the book of Cartan and Eilenberg I would love to hear about it as well!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Both texts are excellent resources for learning homological algebra. Cartan-Eilenberg goes into more detail about what you might describe as prerequisite theory for learning homological algebra, such as rings, modules and associative algebras. Weibel on the other hand talks more about the actual things that you can use homological algebra to calculate such as group cohomology, Hochschild and cyclic (co)homology, and Lie algebra (co)homology (not to say that Cartan-Eilenberg doesn't). That is a very surface level analysis of their differences. In any case I would recommend making use of both.

Comment: @SeraPhim  Thank you very much! for your comment. I started reading the book of Cartan and Eilenberg because I found it hard to fill the detail of Weibel's book on hypercohomology. (I now want to get familiar with the Grothendieck Spetral Sequence) And reading Cartan & Eilenberg, I'm having the 'first' experience with arguments full of multi-complexes. So I wondered whether the book is outdated. By the way, I heard that hypercohomology is outdated. Is there any modern proof of the Grothendieck-Spectral Sequence? I just got curious! Thank you

Comment: @SeraPhim  I'm afraid that I have digressed a little, anyway I felt that Weibel's exposition way more conceptual than Cartan and Eilenberg's. Anyway Thank you again for recommending me to keep using Weibel's book.